# What is a Data Source and where can I find it in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I have just recently started using SQL Server Management Studio. After some hitches, I have managed to create a Database. Inside the DB I have also created some Tables and populate them.

Now I am trying another software that needs to be connected to this DB. When running the software it asks me:

"Data Souce" and "Catalog"

Apparently the "Catalog" is the name of the DB I have created but I don't know what "Data Source" refers. 
It must be a rather begineer question but what does "Data Source" refers to?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Initial Catalog refers to the database name and Data Source refers to your server name.

See more on [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: where can I find the name of my server? I am guessing since I am reaching it in the same machine would it be localhost?

Comment: SELECT @@SERVERNAME

Answer (score 2):

As stated earlier by Darko, Data Source is the name of the server which you are connected to the management studio.
Try to execute SELECT @@SERVERNAME which gives the same output that appears in the object explorer.

[image]